# Calendar Permissions - Resource Missing Options

Tags: microsoft-outlook, permissions, calendar

I am having issues with the calendar permissions for a resource (room).

When right clicking the calendar (I have full access to the mailbox), and clicking 'Permissions', under 'Read', there is only 'None' and 'Full Details'. This is causing issues, as I want the default permission to be set to 'Free/Busy Time' as I would expect.

Why are these extra permissions not available on this mailbox?

[image: Snip of permission issue]

Comment: I tested in my environment and it will show "Free/Busy Time" option. You may have change it somehow. You can refer to:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f7194c1f-7b80-4ca3-9db5-d5782fad95d0/outlook-calendar-permission-no-freebusy-option?forum=outlook  Besides, please make sure you have full access to this mailbox.

Comment: I do have full access to the mailbox. I have tried setting 'Default' to 'Full details', and then closing/opening, but the issue still remains. I shall try this powershell command.